# Automatically close PhantomJs after running script

Tags: phantomjs

I want to run PhantomJs scripts from my program, but since the scripts may not be written by me, I need to make sure PhantomJs exits after the execution are either completed or fails for any reason (e.g., invalid syntax, timeout, etc). So far, All I've read says you must always include the instruction phantom.exit() for PhantomJs to exit. Is there any way to automatically close PhantomJs after it executes a given script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file **run-javascript.js**:

```
var system = require('system');

try {
  for (var i=1; i<system.args.length; i++) {
    var scriptFileName = system.args[i];
    console.log("Running " + scriptFileName + " ...");
    require(scriptFileName);
  }
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(error.stack);
}
finally {
  phantom.exit();
}
```

Then to run your file **myscript.js**:

```
phantomjs run-javascript.js ./myscript.js
```

You have to include an explicit path for the **myscript.js**, i.e. **./myscript.js**, otherwise **phantomjs** will look for the script as a module.

There are three execution scenarios that are handled here:

1. Successful execution, in which case **phantom.exit()** is called in the **finally** clause.
2. Error in the script being run, in which case the **require** function prints a stacktrace and  returns (without throwing any error to the calling code).
3. Error running the script (e.g. it doesn't exist), in which case the **catch** clause prints out the stacktrace and **phantom.exit()** is called in the **finally** clause.